# Given $g(x)$ and $f(g(x))$, solve for $f(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

I've hit a wall on the above question and was unable to find any online examples that also contain trig in $f(g(x))$. I'm sure I am missing something blatantly obvious but I can't quite get it.

$$ g(x)=3x+4 , \quad  f(g(x)) = \cos\left(x^2\right)$$

So far I've managed to get to the point where I have $f(x+8) = \cos\left(x^2\right)$, by solving $g^{-1}(g(x))$ (loosely based on the last bit of advice [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/if-f-o-g-16x-7-and-g-x-2x-1-find-f-x.518117/)), but I can't make that final connection.

My best attempt so far was $f(x)=\cos(x^2-16x+64)$, but while that does result in $x^2$, it still ends up wrong due to it being cosine.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Hint:** $(f \circ g) \circ g^{-1} =f \circ (g \circ g^{-1}) = f$

Answer (score 21):

$$y=g(x)=3x+4$$
$$x=\frac{y-4}{3} \Rightarrow g^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-4}{3}$$
$$f=f \circ (g \circ g^{-1})=(f \circ g) \circ g^{-1} =\cos \left(\frac{x-4}{3} \right)^2 $$